# Having trouble providing `context` to RenderScript.create()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-context, android-camerax

Constructing a RenderScript for my app using the line

```
val rs = RenderScript.create(getContext())
```

Android Studio warns me that "CameraX.getContext can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.camera)"  What should I be doing instead to avoid this warning?

Note: Using `this` instead of `getContext()` generates an error.

Comment: you might want to use, YourAcitivityName.this or want to pass context object if it's a non-activity class

Comment: No luck with `<MyActivityName>.this`.  I tried passing the context up from MainActivity and that just gave me errors.

Comment: then members can't help you without looking at the code. Please follow SO guidelines to form a question [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [keypoints to enhance qulity of question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)